# Store original height in Jquery mouseover

Tags: jquery

I have a simple list and when I rollover the li selector I want to find the original height of the p tag inside that rollover scope that has a class of subtext. I want to store that value somewhere so I can use it on the rollout method. is there a way to store it in the this scope. If I use a global variable it may get changed by another rollover scope before the previous one gets to use it.

I also want to know how I can get the correct height of the selectors text height. 
var pheight = $(this, "p.subtext").height();
the above code is not reading the full height of the text. It seems to be reading the height of the li tag which in the css is set to height:50px;

```
li{
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
color: #191919;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
list-style-type: none;
```

}

**HTML CODE**

```
<body>
<ul>
    <li class="green">
        <div ></div>
        <p><a href="#">Home</a></p>
        <p class="subtext">The front page has more text than any other panel. I want the script to revel different height text.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="yellow">
        <p><a href="#">About</a></p>
        <p class="subtext">More info</p>
    </li>
    <li class="red">
        <p><a href="#">Contact</a></p>
        <p class="subtext">Get in touch</p>
    </li>
    <li class="blue">
        <p><a href="#">Submit</a></p>
        <p class="subtext">Send us your stuff!</p>
    </li>
    <li class="purple">
        <p><a href="#">Terms</a></p>
        <p class="subtext">Legal stuff</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
$("document").ready(function(){

$("li").mouseover(function(){
    var pheight = $(this, "p.subtext").height();
    console.log(pheight);
    $(this).stop().animate({height:150}, {duration: 600, easing: "easeOutExpo"} );
})

$("li").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height:50}, {duration: 600, easing: "easeOutExpo"} );
})
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,  you need to use the selector the other way round -- `$('p.subtext', this)`. More obviously, use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find):

```
var pheight = $(this).find('p.subtext').height();
```

Then you can store the data on the element itself with [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data):

```
$(this).data('pheight', pheight);
```

You can retrieve it in the `mouseout` function with `data` again:

```
$(this).stop().animate({height: $(this).data('pheight')}, {duration: 600, easing: "easeOutExpo"} );
```

Comment: Thanks lonesomeday, In the Jquery site it has an example like this 

jQuery.data(document.body, 'foo', 52);

The element being document.body "foo" being the key and 52 being the value. 
What I'm not getting in the above example, is the value of key "foo" being stored on the body element or on Jquery DOM itself. 

In your example:$(this).data('pheight', pheight);

the value of key named "pheight" is getting stored on the the in scope (this) p.subtext element. 
Is this correct in my assumption. If so maybe you can explain why the Jquery site uses a extra parameter called element?

Comment: @Chapsterj There are two methods: `$(selection).data` and `$.data`. The first takes a jQuery selection, then binds data to it. The second binds data to one element only, in a slightly less readable fashion. The following are identical in effect: `$(this).data('foo', 'bar')` and `$.data(this, 'foo', 'bar')`. I've used the more readable version above (and linked to it), although `$.data` is a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function allows you to store arbitrary data associated with the specified element. Returns the value that was set.